# Passing data from Blade to modal in Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, modal-dialog

I have a situation like display table with different columns, say the first column is id and the second column is name, the third column has a button which on click opens up a modal; the data in the table is coming from foreach loop.

I want to pass the id to the modal when button clicked.

```
                                    <td>{{ $emp->req_id}} </td>

                                    <td>{{ $emp->empid}} </td>
                                    <td>{{ $emp->visit_title}} </td>
                                    <td>{{ $emp->stays_nights}}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $emp->apply_date }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $emp->travel_charges }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $emp->hotel_charges }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $emp->meal_charges }}</td>

                                    <td>{{ $emp->approv_status}}</td>

                                @endforeach
                                </tr> 
                                </tbody>
```

Comment: If button is inside the loop you can add data attributes to it and manage them on the click event.

Comment: please explain your answer in brief as I m a little new to the technology ..

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this, you can use jquery

step(1) add this code in your blade file

```
 <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target-id="{{ $emp->id }}" data-target="#modelName">Button name </button>
```

step (2)  define your jquery method

```
 <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#modelName").on("show.bs.modal", function (e) {
                    var id = $(e.relatedTarget).data('target-id');
                    $('#pass_id').val(id);
                });
            });

</script>
```

step (3) Make Modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modelName" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
                             aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
                            <div class="modal-dialog data-dialog-centerd" role="document">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                            <span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
                                        <h4 class="modal-title text-center" id="myModalLabel">Model header Name</h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        <form class="form-horizontal" action="#"
                                              method="post"
                                              enctype="multipart/form-data">

                                            {{ csrf_field() }}

                                            <div class="portlet-body form">
                                                <div class="form-body">
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <input class="form-control" name="name" type="text"
                                                               id="pass_id">
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: highly appreciated the answer but I think none of them are working .. just wanted to echo the id in modal on correct selection of row in foreach loop..

Answer (score 1):

give  an identifiable class say employee `<tr class="employee">` and put the id of the entry in the same tag like this `<tr class="employee" data-id="{{$emp->id}}">`. Then when you would click on the row you could do something like this:

```
const employees = document.querySelectorAll('.employee');
employees.forEach( employee => {
 employee.addEventListener(e => {
  const employeeId = e.target.getAttribute('data-id');
  // do what you need to do with the id 
 })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The Answer To The Question (The One That Worked For Me)

Step#1 Add Button in the column Of the table:

```
<button type="button" onclick="myfunction( {{$a->id }})" > My Button </button>
```

Step#2 Add Script for The function that is calling from the button:

```
                        <script>

                          function myfunction(e){

                            var x = e;

                             $('#edit_req_id').val(req_id);  //The id where to pass the value

                              $('#modal-block-popout').modal('show'); //The id of the modal to show
                            };

                         </script>
```

Step#3: Add Modal to which you want to pass the value to:

```
                      <div class="modal fade" id="modal-block-popout">
                       <div class="modal-content ">
                        <div class="block-options">
                  <button type="button" class="btn-block-option" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" name="btn"> <i class="fa fa-fw fa-times"></i></button>
                       </div>
                        <div class="block-content">
                   <input class="form-control form-control-alt " type="text" id="edit_req_id" name="empid">

                    </div

                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to refactor this

```
<a title="Approve" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-block-popout" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm" href="approve<?php $emp->id; ?>">Approve </a>
```

to

```
<button type="button" title="Approve" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm btn-toggle-modal-block-popout" data-id="<?php $emp->id; ?>" >Approve</button>
```

And add this Javascript

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn-toggle-modal-block-popout', function() {

var id = $(this).attr('data-id');

//DO WHAT EVER YOU NEED

$('#modal-block-popout').modal('show');

};
```

Of course for disapprove it will be the same.

Comment: highly appreciated the answer but script is not running on button click ..

Comment: Explain me better your request, you want to write the ID somewhere (a hidden input i suppose?) in your modal, right?

Comment: as mentioned above in the code ,, the button is placed in the first column of table ,and rest of the columns are filled with data coming from database using foreach loop .. just want " when I click the button ,the button get the id of that row of table and display it in modal " .. i.e just wanting to pass the data of selected row to the modal for edting or other operations ..

Comment: So the solution it's the same, just pass as data attributes as you need and populate input fields on the modal

Comment: sir I have posted my code again ,, will u b more specific and make it correct ,, I m new to the script .. your help will b highly appreciated ..

Comment: thank you so very much .. it is exactly the same what I wanted .. thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me you can try this :

```
          <i class="mdi mdi-eyedropper px-2" type="button" data-bs-toggle="modal"
                                        data-target-id="{{ $item->id }}" data-bs-target="#modelName"></i>
```

then :

**Modal for Update**

---

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modelName" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog data-dialog-centerd" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title text-center" id="myModalLabel">Model header Name</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="form-horizontal" action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                    {{ csrf_field() }}

                    <div class="portlet-body form">
                        <div class="form-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" name="name" type="text" id="pass_id">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

then

---

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#modelName").on("show.bs.modal", function(e) {
            var id = $(e.relatedTarget).data('target-id');
            $('#pass_id').val(id);
        });
    });
</script>
```